# Sharepoint 2013 Search Refiner button

Tags: search, query, refiner

I'm been looking at our search page and I'm trying to create buttons that will just searches a particular list;

For example;

a search results page, that has COURSES DOCUMENTS PEOPLE and clicking courses will just show results from the courses list, so acting like a refiner but like a query search too;

Is this possible? I looked at refiners, but it looks like they show the refiner options etc, where I want it to query different lists, as I've created seperate lists for containing, courses, people and documents;

Hope someone can help

Comment: You aren't looking for a refiner, you are looking to create a new Search Vertical. Search for new Result Source and Vertical.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you want in the spirit that is consistent with SharePoint search experience is a search vertical in a search center. Essentially, you create a separate search page which is using a separate result source, which filters the search results the way you want, while also allowing users to enter a search query. In your case, you would want 3 result sources and 3 pages to display results from those sources (Courses, Documents, People). Then you would configure the search center navigation to include these pages in the search verticals.

This is a very good article explaining all the steps in detail (along with some screenshots - you can check these out to understand how the end solution will look like): https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/12/how-to-add-a-custom-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

-For the finer you have to customise the search refiner webpart

for the more details to search on the specific list visit [this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-search-content-from-specific-sharepoint-list-in-content-search-web-part1)

Comment: I've read and used that before, but how would I get that functionality to work on a button; so if I click COURSES if brings back results just from the COURSES list;